# Neo4j 2.2.9 to neo4j 3.0.3 database migration

Tags: neo4j

Used the 
**neo4j-admin import -mode database -database dbname -from location**

Got the message :Imported data from <> to <>
I could see the databse created into the neo4j-enterprise-3.0.3\data\databases directory

Then i start the  neo4j server. I dont see error log in debug.log or neo4j.log 
But when i try to see the contents of the in the browseron localhost 7474 i see empty db with no labels or  anything..

> Database Information
>    Node labels 
>   No labels in database Relationship types
>    No relationships in database Property keys No property keys in
>    database Database Version:
>    3.0.3 Name: neo4j-hpp-db-default_CTDCA_HKGDT Size:
>    88.24 KiB

Why dont I see  the data?

Answer (score 1):

Stop the 2.2.9 instance gracefully (aka make sure there's no unclean shutdown).

Copy over your datastore from `neo4j-2.2.9/data/graph.db` to `neo4j-3.0.3/data/databases/graph.db` (not the additional `databases` part).

Fire up the database on 3.0.3 and keep an eye on the files in `logs`.